# Ubuntu 16.04 Updating issue

Tags: 16.04, updates, multiarch, binary, multiverse

Does anyone know what I should do to fix this problem?

I recently receive these after I do `sudo apt-get update`:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'public/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'public/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-foreign-architecture/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'foreign-architecture'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-multiarch/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'multiarch'
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also the terminal output of `sudo dpkg --print-architecture`
 is `amd64`, and the terminal output of `sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

is

```
i386
foreign-architecture
multiarch
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo dpkg --print-architecture` and `sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`. The repository error is because there is no xenial repository there... the latest is trusty. Edit your deb line to correct.

Comment: I did update the post.
Can you please explain what you mean when you say "The repository error is because there is no xenial repository there... the latest is trusty. Edit your deb line to correct. "
I am a Ubuntu newbie and dont know a lot about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding...

My request for data...

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
foreign-architecture  <== this is wrong
multiarch             <== this is wrong
```

In `terminal`...

To fix 90% of the errors that you're getting...

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture foreign-architecture
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture multiarch
```

To fix the remaining 10% of the errors that you're getting... we fix the PPA...

```
grep tualatrix /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
* note the filename returned
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filename # replace filename with name from previous step
* change "xenial" to "trusty"
* save file and quit gedit

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question for the second part.
When I type `grep tualatrix /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`  in the terminal the output is:

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial main`

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu xenial main`

what is the filename for `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filename ` ?

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` and change both instances of xenial to trusty. The first part of my answer went OK? Do the `sudo dpkg --print...` commands again, and make sure that you get `amd64` and `i386` answers.

Comment: wheI type `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` the file that opens is empty...

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion, you duplicated the path to the file... the entire path, including the filename is... `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list`, but the filename by itself is `tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list`. So you want `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list`.

Comment: Thanks, it is almost working i belive. I did `sudo apt-get update` and it shows this at the end `W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg: Signature by key FE85409EEAB40ECCB65740816AF0E1940624A220 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)`

Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: That's a normal message. The author hasn't upgraded their repository from the older SHA1 signatures to the newer SHA256 signatures. Also, I think with your "reputation", you should be able to vote my answer too, by clicking the grey up arrow above the zero. Thanks!

Comment: addendum: by "reputation" I'm referring to the "7 .2" that appears under your name. It means a rep of 7 and 2 bronze stars. You may need a minimum rep of 15 to also vote though.